# Ubuntu decrypts drive but then goes to (initramfs) _ black screen

Tags: boot

Black screen says this after I am apparently able to decrypt my drive:

```
BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubunu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) _
```

Flashing underscore...
I have no idea what to do, thanks in advance for any help!